# How can I add the Like button to a website running on DotNetNuke CMS?

Tags: facebook-like, dotnetnuke

We recently re-designed our website http://www.lryc.ie, it now runs on the DotNetNuke CMS system. I want to add a Like button but I can't use the method described on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ because it doesn't work with DotNetNuke. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

you can use widgets for like buttons.
I hope this link can help you : http://dnnwidgets.com/Widgets/Facebook